# Single query: Update specific value in document, else insert whole document

Tags: mongodb

I have a collection where this document may exist:

```js
_id : 12345,
param1 : 1,
param2 : 'stuff'
```

If it exists, I would like to update `param1` to `0`. If not, I would like to insert the whole document with `param1` set to `0`, but also including `param2`

```py
db.stuff.updateOne(
    { "_id" : 12345 },
    { $set: {param1 : 0} },
    { upsert : true})
```

The above query won't suffice because it won't include `param2`.

```js
_id : 12345,
param1 : 0
```

Is it possible for this to be done in one call?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [$setOnInsert](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/setOnInsert/):

```
db.stuff.updateOne(
    { "_id" : 12345 },
    { $set: {param1 : 0}, $setOnInsert: { param2: 'stuff' } },
    { upsert : true})
```